# How to dot product 1D and 2D lists in python without using NumPy or .dot?

Tags: python, list, dot-product

With given 2D and 1D lists, I have to dot product them. But I have to calculate them without using `.dot`.

For example, I want to make these lists

```
matrix_A = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30, 31]]
vector_x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

to  this output

```
result_list = [ 14  38  62  86 110 134 158 182]
```

How can I do it by only using lists(not using `NumPy array` and `.dot`) in python?

Comment: I don;t know how you are able to multiply these two things without there column-row matching ?

Comment: oh, I  should multiply them with row factors. I have to do it by list, so it is a little different with array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension with nested for loops.

```py
matrix_A = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30, 31]]
vector_x = [0, 1, 2, 3]

result_list = [sum(a*b for a,b in zip(row, vector_x)) for row in matrix_A]

print(result_list)
```

Output:

```
[14, 38, 62, 86, 110, 134, 158, 182]
```

Edit: Removed the square brackets in the list comprehension following @fshabashev's comment.

Comment: you can also replace square brackets in list comprehension
from `sum([a*b for a,b in zip(row, vector_x)])`
to 
`sum(a*b for a,b in zip(row, vector_x))`
that would make the code a bit faster for larger matrices

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind using numpy, this is a solution

```
import numpy as np

matrix_A = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30, 31]]
vector_x = [0, 1, 2, 3]

res = np.sum(np.array(matrix_A) * np.array(vector_x), axis=1)
print(res)
```